# RavenDB client 3 errors when enumerating streamed results

Tags: c#, json, session, ravendb

Just wasted a whole day on this...

Opening a Stream from a query to copy down a large index of documents, each of about 10K:

**var query = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery("RecordsToExport");**

**using (var enumerator = session.Advanced.Stream(query))**

**{**

**while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {}**

**}**

Try this on v3.0.3599 and after 300-450 records you will get a JSON parser exception complaining about invalid characters, or value parse errors.
The exact location it occurs changes each run, even though the documents are unchanged, and dumping the stream URL directly shows that all of the records are valid, leading me to assume it's a client issue.

Comment: What is the actual error? Can you show fiddler output?

Answer (score -1):

My workaround is to retrieve the data in batches, with a SKIP(counter).TAKE(200) on the query, and increase the maximum requests per session:

**session.Advanced.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession = 3000;**

So if you're getting reports that a record has invalid JSON and won't deserialise, it my be related to this instead.
Just making this public so (hopefully) other people don't waste as much time on it as I have.